# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Mainboard Asus P8H67-M with UEFI BIOS?

Tags: installation, asus, uefi

I've looked at several posts but haven't really found an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell it should have the same BIOS/UEFI as my ASUS P8Z68-V and that works just fine.

Comment: and what about the overcklocking tools and intel driver update(as seen last days ago)?

Comment: You cannot install Windows drivers in Ubuntu and I doubt you can run overclocking tools for Windows through WINE in Ubuntu (but I haven't tested *that*). There's also a bunch of overclocking stuff in the BIOS/UEFI, but again - haven't played around with that yet.

Answer (score 2):

"Yes it works" !

I'm typing this on a ubuntu box built with an Asus P8H67 and id works great.
Only problem : hibernate and suspend do not work, at least with ubuntu 11.10.

Some new info on this : these patch should get suspend working on the P8H67 M. Unfornutalely you have to build your own kernel to use them and I don't know if they will be backported to 12.04 (should be included in kernel 3.3, and 12.04 will use 3.2)

Kernel 3.3 for Ubuntu 12.04 can also be downloaded here: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/05/linux-kernel-335-released-installation.html

Suspend works for me now with Asus P8H67, but hibernate still doesn't.

Comment: You can improve your answer a bit by at least adding "Yes it works". Someone flagged this, possibly because it appears to be more of a comment.

Comment: Some new info on this : [these patch](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.acpi.devel/51405/focus=51407) should get suspend working on the P8H67 M. Unfornutalely you have to build your own kernel to use them and I don't know if they will be backported to 12.04 (should be included in kernel 3.3, and 12.04 will use 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my P8P67 Pro.  I originally had it installed in bios mode but I recently reformatted and set up the GPT partition table and EFI system partition and am now booting in EFI mode.